# Stock taking items in Python Dataframe into a dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe

Suppose I have a Python Dataframe:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| A | Val 1 |
| A | Val 2 |
| B | Val A |
| B | Val B |
| B | Val C |
| B | Val D |

I want to stock-take Column B into a dictionary with key = unique values of Column A, as such:

out = {    'A': ['Val 1','Val 2'],
'B': ['Val A','Val B','Val C','Val D'] }

How would I do that?

I tried making a pivot table but it only allows aggregating column B; I want them as separate value in a list.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`:

```
out = df.groupby("Column A")["Column B"].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'A': ['Val 1', 'Val 2'], 'B': ['Val A', 'Val B', 'Val C', 'Val D']}
```